# EHIC while interrupting studies?

Tags: uk, germany, health, insurance

I'm a German citizen and a student in the UK. I'm currently interrupting my studies for half a year and I'm planning to live in Germany for that time. Do you know if EHIC will still cover me during this kind of stay?

Comment: Why do you need EHIC in Germany as a German citizen ??

Comment: Germany doesn't have a single payer health care system like the UK. A German health insurance is quite a costly thing if you're not enrolled as a student in Germany.

Comment: EHIC is for usage in a EEA country different than your country of citizenship.

Comment: No, it's "different than your country of residence". The NHS doesn't really care whether I have a UK citizenship or not. Finding out what's my country of residence seems to be harder than I thought, though. I'm enrolled in Britain and I will most likely return there. But also, I'm not really only on holiday here in Germany.

Comment: Isn't the question really if the NHS still covers you?  My understanding is that the EHIC card itself is just to let the different systems bill each other, and that the really important thing is that you are enrolled.

Comment: Yes, that might be sort of the same question.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the EHIC only cover "emergency" cover - a regular doctor's appointment, or repeated medication would be out of scope for it.

Comment: @CMaster: http://www.nhs.uk/NHSEngland/Healthcareabroad/countryguide/Pages/healthcareinGermany.aspx states otherwise.

Comment: Is the UK still your country of residence if you're a German citizen who's living in Germany for a year?

Comment: I honestly don't know.

Comment: Will you resume your studies in the UK after that? Still be registered at the university?

Comment: I think http://www.nhs.uk/NHSEngland/Healthcareabroad/movingabroad/Pages/Studyingabroad.aspx pretty much sums it up.

Comment: @CMaster Actually, it also covers routine care or care for preexisting conditions appropriate for the length of stay (which can be one or two years for students, as long as they intend to return to their country of usual residence at the end of the stay abroad). What it does not cover is going abroad specifically to get medical care (or give birth).

Comment: Yes, I'm still registered and will resume my studies. I'm not in Germany to study, so that page doesn't apply to me at all.

Comment: Does any of this apply to you ? `If you are insured by another EEA country but live in the United Kingdom, you are not entitled to a UK-issued EHIC. You should contact the relevant authority in the country you are insured by and request an EHIC.
Important: If your circumstances change, you may lose your entitlement to a UK-issued EHIC. If you then use your EHIC abroad, you may be liable for the full cost of treatment received. You may lose your entitlement to a UK-issued EHIC when you move abroad, take up work abroad, or change your residency status.`

Comment: If "when you move abroad" applies to me, then yes.